# An unexpected version directory `Assets` was encountered for Private Pod

Tags: cocoapods, gitlab

I have built a private CocoaPods repo that is  used in my company. This repo can be pushed to gitlab.com. The procedure is like this:

```
//1
pod lib create PZResources

//2 change podspec
//3 add directory and images to PZResources.
//4 push these changes to gitlab.com. Then add tag and push tags to server.

//5 vertify spec 
pod spec lint --sources=https://zlanchun@gitlab.com/zlanchun/PZResources.git

//6 pod repo add 
pod repo add PZResources https://zlanchun@gitlab.com/zlanchun/PZResources.git

//6 pod repo push
pod repo push PZResources PZResources.podspec --sources=https://zlanchun@gitlab.com/zlanchun/PZResources.git
```

Then I open a new project, pod it, and add new library to the Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '7.0'
source 'https://zlanchun@gitlab.com/zlanchun/PZResources.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'PZDemo' do
# Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
# use_frameworks!
pod "PZResources"
# Pods for PZDemo

end
```

After the above steps, this error occurs:

```
[!] An unexpected version directory `Assets` was encountered for the `/Users/z/.cocoapods/repos/PZResources/PZResources` Pod in the `PZResources` repository.
```

I think my procedure is correct, but this error occurred. I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With times go, I found this answer for it.

Because the repo is private for me, I need a Specs repo to collect these private repos. But I don't have one. So the error occur.

Then follow below steps, I solved this error.

```
1.Create a gitlab repo called Specs that used to collect private repo.
2.add repo and push private repo to Specs.
3.In Podfile, add source url.
4.pod install
```

For example:

1.delete pod repo in your computer cache

```
$ pod repo list
```

If you have PZResources repo ,then you should delete it.

```
$ pod repo remove PZResources
```

2.add lib repo to remote Specs repo

```
$ pod repo add PZResources https://zlanchun@gitlab.com/zlanchun/Specs.git
```

3.push lib repo to remote Specs repo. You can use --sources for it.

```
$ pod repo push PZResources PZResources.podspec --sources=https://zlanchun@gitlab.com/zlanchun/Specs.git
```

Maybe it need an username and password, just complete it.

4.Create a test project and pod init, then in Podfile add the info below:

```
//search private Specs. If this Specs cann't have repo, then seacrch github Specs.
source 'https://zlanchun@gitlab.com/zlanchun/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'TestPrivateLibRepo' do
    pod 'PZResources'
end
```